# My GameScene reloads whenever my Text view updates

Tags: swift, swiftui, sprite-kit

I have a SwiftUI/SpriteKit project.

I'm using a SwiftUI `SpriteView` to display my `GameScene`.

Whenever `mainData.numOfBallsInCup` is incremented, it updates a `Text` view.

**Here's the problem:** When the `Text` view is updated, it causes `GameScene` to be reloaded. GameScene's `sceneDidLoad()` runs each time, and the scene regresses to its initial state.

My `ContentView` is something like this:

```
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var mainData: MainData
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            Group {
                if mainData.showSpriteScene {
                    SpriteView(scene: GameScene(), transition: SKTransition.reveal(with: .down, duration: 1.0))
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                    VStack {
                        Text("\(mainData.numOfBallsInCup)")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        Text("BALLS")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    }
                        .position(x: geo.size.width * 0.5, y: geo.size.height * 0.06)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I have my `Text` view updating without reloading my `GameScene`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scene is a model, and you create new scene (right in call) on each update, so `SpriteView` thinks it should rebuild.

Try the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var mainData: MainData
    
    @State private var scene = GameScene()  // << here, or put in MainData !!

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            Group {
                if mainData.showSpriteScene {
                    SpriteView(scene: scene,    // << here !!
                               transition: SKTransition.reveal(with: .down, duration: 1.0))
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
```